# input and specify the character to print out and the number of characters to print on each line

Tags: java, loops, character

I am trying to allow the user to specify the character to print out and the number of characters to print on each line.

I tried to reach this goal with the following class and method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test3char {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //insert the character 
        System.out.println("insert character");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str= keyboard.nextLine();
        //insert the time you would like to print the character 
        System.out.println("insert the number of times you would like to print the car");
        int n = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.close();

        // loop 
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=n;i=i+1) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        }

    }

}
```

I have the following error at line 17:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at test3char.main(test3char.java:17)
```

How I can fix this loop in order to print the string input by the user by `n` time on the same line.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you share a sample input and the output that's supposed to be generated for it?

Comment: Why are you printing `str.charAt(i)`? Do you know what that means?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but instead of using [**charAt**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) inside your for-loop, instead try something like this where you use **[charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))** earlier on:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the character you want repeated: ");
    char character = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of times you would like to print the character:");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      System.out.print(character);
    }
  }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
Please enter the character you want repeated:  a
Please enter the number of times you would like to print the character: 5
aaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from `0` to `length() - 1`. The first char value of the sequence is at index `0`, the next at index `1`, and so on, as for array indexing.

You're going from `1` to `length()`, not `0` to `length() - 1`.

Comment: @JohnS. Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer (using the tick underneath the voting buttons) if you found it useful.